# Why X-Forwarded-For is changed inside varnish?

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl, x-forwarded-for

I am running a varnish server on top of my backend server and under a SSL terminator. SSL terminator returns a `X-Forwarded-For` header with the real ip address from where the request actually came, but for some weird reason, `X-Forwarded-For` is changed to ip address of the varnish cache server. Like below:

```
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For : <One-ip>  <----------
-   ReqHeader      Range: bytes=156478-
-   ReqHeader      User-Agent: Some Stupid Phone
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Encoding: identity
-   ReqHeader      Host: host.example.com
-   ReqHeader      Connection: Keep-Alive
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: <another-ip> <-----------
```

I want to capture the IP address of actual client and send it to log. What should I do?

Comment: Varnish should append its ip to the x-forwarded-for header as intermediate equipment does. What is your vcl_recv?

Comment: There is no ReqUnset in your log, the Header should be duplicated (or appended), not replaced. Can you dump the header you receive in your backends?

Comment: @BenjaminBaumann This things happen just before entering  vcl_recv. I have logged `X-Forwarded-For` and `remote.ip` at the start of `vcl_recv`, but I got the modified ip  always.

Comment: Could you shared your vcl_recv and vcl_init (if any) ? Which value of X-forwarded-for do you get on your backend ?

Comment: If is Varnish 4, you should know this:  "In many cases, people unintentionally removed X-Forwarded-For when implementing their own vcl_recv. Therefore it has been moved to before vcl_recv, so if you don't want an IP added to it, you should remove it in vcl_recv."  https://varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/whats-new/upgrading-4.0.html#x-forwarded-for-is-now-set-before-vcl-recv